# background-position y axis issue in mozilla firefox

Tags: css

I am trying and that is not working. Works fine in chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox. This property is not supported ?  Any alternative?

```
.background {
  background:url('icon.png') no-repeat;
  background-position:0 4;
  width:32px;
  height:40px;
}
```

Just started CSS.

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in any browser.

Comment: I can see that, but the browser can't, so you have to tell the browser. That's my point. Also, if you've just started CSS, how come you've answered 70+ questions about [css]? If I've just started CSS, how come I've answered more than a thousand of them? You're still young and inexperienced - I suggest you keep your opinions of skill level to yourself for the time being, instead of questioning what are otherwise simple hints that lead you to the answer so you can learn.

Comment: What do you mean by `background-position:0 4`? Because I have no idea (and your browser doesn't, either).

Comment: I'd prefer a description of what you mean by "not working". Because there is no W3C standard for what that means.

Comment: @AspiringAqib - Hold on....*puts fingers to forehead*....nope, I'm still unable to read your mind, and thus have absolutely no idea how you want your web page design to fit together.

Comment: 0_o So you answered the questions unprofessionally?

Comment: Why did you choose to act unprofessionally?

Comment: @AspiringAqib - Look, what it comes down to is this: do you actually want help or not? If so, then tell us what you think you mean by `background-position:0 4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Background position values are required to have a unit value for non-zero positions. So if you want the icon to be 4px off the top, change it to:

```
background-position: 0 4px;
```

You can also include the position in the shorthand, like so:

```
 background: url('icon.png') 0px 4px no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks Got it to have unit with values always. Yeah!